# generating dict values like a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
    sentence="one fish two fish red fish blue fish one 
    red two blue"
    sentence='start '+sentence+' end'
    word_list=sentence.split(' ')
    d={}
    for i in range(len(word_list)-1):
        d[word_list[i]]=word_list[i+1]

    print word_list
    print d
```

Thus, i get the *word_list*:

```
    ['start', 'one', 'fish', 'two', 'fish', 'red',\ 
    'fish', 'blue', 'fish', 'one', 'red', 'two',\ 
    'blue', 'end']
```

and  the *d*:

```
    {'blue': 'end', 'fish': 'one', 'two': 'blue',\
     'one': 'red', 'start': 'one', 'red': 'two'}
```

But I need a dict with values looked like lists of every possible word followed after the key-word. For example, word '*fish*' is followed by 4 words, so I need:

```
    'fish':['two', 'red', 'blue', 'one']
```

'*blue*' is followed by '*fish*' and '*end*'

```
    'blue':['one', 'end']
```

etc.

Please, any ideas?

The task is the first step to generation random sentence.

Thanks))

Comment: `blue` is followed by `fish` and `end`, not `one`. Are you not counting previously used key words? if so, what is the order? Should `'one':' 'fish' 'red'`? Why is there an `*`?

Comment: kabanus, thank you, it was a misprint. Fixed

Answer (score 4):

you may try this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

sentence="one fish two fish red fish blue fish one red two blue"
word_list = sentence.split()

d = defaultdict(list)
for a, b in zip( word_list, word_list[1:]) :
    d[a].append(b)

print d
```

it gives:

```
{
    "blue": [ "fish" ], 
    "fish": [ "two", "red", "blue", "one" ], 
    "two": [ "fish", "blue" ], 
    "red": [ "fish", "two" ], 
    "one": [ "fish", "red" ]
}
```

and you don't need to add `start` and `end` to avoid accessing elements beyond the list size.